# Redirect standard streams back to Console and Keyboard in C++

Tags: c++

After redirecting standard input and output to some files(for example) using **freopen** how can I redirect them back to where they were at the very beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can duplicate/clone the initial FD's using `id = fcntl(blah,F_DUPFD,0)`, and then use `dup2(0,id)` to copy it back (after closing stdin!), then reopen the file using fdopen().  Repeat for the others.  However, that probably doesn't get you what you want exactly - it gets you a random filehandle that is associated with FD 0, not changing 'stdin'.

Another kind-of ugly option is to spawn off a thread (which implicitly dups stdin/etc), fdreopen them, do your processing, then exit the thread (closing the reopened stdin/etc) and unblock the main process (which never was changed).  This is indirect but probably both portable and guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can not, since underlying file descriptors was closed. But on windows you can try to open special file "CON", which corresponds to console.